# Permission to delete data from a table

Tags: ssms-2017

My user role assigned in SSMS is datareader. Can a modification be made to SSMS so I can act as a datawriter for just one specific table - the “External Data” table which is among the many tables I have permissions to read.  I need to have the ability to delete data from the external data table as needed while keeping the permissions set and my role as datareader with all other tables.